# Why is our PWA app not installable on some devices?

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

We published our PWA app on the website. It follows the guidelines for a proper PWA app. Most of our users can add it to the home sceen as expected, both on Android and iOS. However for some this options fails.

- The problem appears only on Android & Chrome. People, who experiance this problem have versions of the browser that supports PWA.
- The error message displayed means the `beforeinstallprompt` event was not fired.

Can anybody suggest how to troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, we've figured it out. What happened is users were visiting the page following the link in Instagram, hence it was opening inside the Instagram's browser, instead of normal browser. This one doesn't support PWA.